# Commit signing using sourcetree on windows

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-sign

Currently (13th Feb 2018) Sourcetree supports [commit signing in Mac version](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/setup-gpg-to-sign-commits-within-sourcetree-765397791.html) only.

And from [this question](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/210979/does-sourcetree-support-git-commit-gpg-sign) (since 2013) commit signing still isn't available in Windows version.

So is it possible to sign commit in Windows version of sourcetree?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, the answer is yes and no.

The work around I've figured out is as follow (I assumed that you've already the GPG key setup, if not follow [github's tutorial on how to set it up](https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-with-gpg/))

### Step 1 Install git shell for Windows

(If you haven't already)

### Step 2 Make sure sourcetree use system's git

Press `ctrl+,` go to git tab and click `Use System Git`[image]

### Step 3 Configure git to sign every commit (optional)

From powershell (or you can use the built-in terminal from `terminal` icon in sourcetree).

Enter `git config commit.gpgsign true` - this will configure git to automatically sign all commits **in CURRENT repository**.

If you want to sign every commits in **EVERY repository** use `git config --global commit.gpgsign true` instead.

---

**Note** If you choose to skip step 3 make sure to add `-S` every time you commit (`git commit -S`)  or your commit won't be sign.

---

### Drawback

Of course this way have a drawback.

Every time you commit. You have to do it in terminal. If you try to commit using sourcetree's commit button an error will occur

```
gpg: cannot open tty `no tty': No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Apart from that, you can use every other features sourcetree have (push, pull, fetch, merge etc.) as usual.

Edit : This drawback has been solved by [ahmad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675983/commit-signing-using-sourcetree-on-windows/#46472889).

Comment: You also need to configure signing key ID : git config --global user.signingkey ABBBBBBBAAAAAA

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar issue & I followed @theminer3746 answer to set it up.

I was able to fix the no tty error & have a dialog to enter the password using the following steps

- Install: https://www.gpg4win.org
- Load keys into Kleopatra program `([Your homedir]/.gnupg/secring.gpg)`
- Run this command in your terminal: `git config --global gpg.program "c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"`

Comment: When trying to import my GPG key with Kleopatra as [described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46472889/7010420) by ahmad I encountered the problem that the `secring.gpg` wasn't present in my gnupg folder. This seems to be a change which came with GnuPG 2.1. A workaround is to create this file yourself with the following command in Git Bash: `gpg --export-secret-keys >~/.gnupg/secring.gpg` (h/t [rtyley](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp/issues/72#issuecomment-294285419)). After this the import in Kleopatra should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you have not created GPG Key, then head to github's tutorial on GPG keys [here](https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-with-gpg/)

Open Sourcetree and click the Terminal button on the top-right corner.
[Click on terminal icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DlvJ.jpg)
(I don't have enough reputation points to post an image. I'll update the image when I get sufficient reputation points :) ).

Enter the following commands

```
$ git config commit.gpgsign true
```

You need to have a GPG Signing key in order to sign the commit. Check for existing keys by using the following command

```
$ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
```

For example, if your output is

```
/Users/hubot/.gnupg/secring.gpg
------------------------------------
sec   4096R/3AA5C34371567BD2 2016-03-10 [expires: 2017-03-10]
uid                          Hubot 
ssb   4096R/42B317FD4BA89E7A 2016-03-10
```

***3AA5C34371567BD2*** is your Signing Key.

Then, execute the following command

```
$ git config commit.signingkey YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

If you want to sign every repository, then add a `--global` flag to above commands. For example,

```
$ git config --global commit.gpgsign true
$ git config --global commit.signingkey YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

No need to download any other software for signing your commits.

## Method 2

Open your config file present in .git folder of your repository. And add/update the following options.

```
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
    signingkey = YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

Try to commit after updating the above options.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "user.signingkey" instead of  "commit.gpgsign"?